# Using the digits 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 to make a 5 digit number, where digits cannot be repeated, how many have 4 before 2?

Tags: combinatorics

I understand how to determine how many total possible 5-digit numbers with no repeating numbers you can find, I am just not sure how to figure out the last part

Comment: You can consider 5 cases: 4 is the first number, 4 is the second number, etc. and add up the possibilities of each.

Comment: The numbers formable are finite right? Have you tried something as simple as how many are there where the 4 is in the 5th spot and the 2 is in the 4th? 3rd?2nd?1st? Then move the 4 to the 4th spot and the 2 to the 3rd,2nd,1st. Etc

Comment: Alternatively you can argue by symmetry there must be as many numbers with 4 before 2 as 2 before 4.

Comment: Half of all ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By symmetry, having 4 before 2 and 2 before 4 are essentially the same case. Since there are a total of $5!=120$ combinations, there are $\frac{120}{2}=60$ numbers with 4 before 2.

Comment: Elegant answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are 5 non repeatable digits there are $ 5! $ possible sequences of such digits.

If there was a sixth digit in a *fixed* place (the end or beginning) there would still be $ 5! $ possible sequences of the digits.

The requirement is that 4 comes before 2 in the sequence. I am assuming 'first' means that 4 is to the left of 2.

There are several positions these digits can be placed in:

$$ 4XXX2 $$

$$ 4XX2X $$

$$ 4X2XX $$

$$ 42XXX $$

$$ X4XX2 $$

$$ X4X2X $$

$$ X42XX $$

$$ XX4X2 $$

$$ XX42X $$

$$ XXX42 $$

There are 10 total sequences where 4 can be before 2 if each other digit is the same.

For each of the ten sequences if the X's were replaced with digits 1,3, and 5, there would be $3!$ different possible sequences for each.

The number of possible sequences of 1,2,3,4 and 5 where 4 is before 2 is

$$ 10 * (3!) = 60 $$

Comment: Notice that there are $\binom{5}{2} = 10$ ways to choose the positions occupied by the $4$ and the $2$, and one way to arrange them in the selected positions so that the $4$ appears before the $2$.

Comment: There are 20 ways to choose the positions for 4 and 2 if order is not preserved. There are only 10 when 4 must come before 2.